# Does nmkr.io provide public api?

Tags: cardano-node, nami-wallet, api, cardano-api

Does nmkr.io provide free usable cardano apis for NFTS or do we have to mint the nfts and build a project on their platform something like that ...and then we can use their api because in their apis it (projectuid, nftuid)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question about what the API should do? What actions are you looking to execute and what data are you looking for?

Comment: basically I want to fetch the "sold price" and "timestamp" of that txn if a user sells his nft

Answer (score 1):

You have to register on their site, then create a project. If you have an existing nft project, you'll need the policy keys and a wallet. The items labeled as projectuid and nftuid are custom IDs you get from nmkr.io. So while you don't need to mint with them, you need to do all these setup steps before using their API. At least, I'm assuming you're looking at `/v2/UpdateMetadata/{projectuid}/{nftuid}` since those are the two params you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out if an NFT has been transferred to another wallet, you have to check the transactions the NFT was involved in. You can get that information from the blockchain using for example the koios API.

You can get all transactions (with timestamp) using: https://api.koios.rest/#get-/asset_txs

If you need more information, e.g. the addresses involved, you can get this information from another API endpoint:
https://api.koios.rest/#post-/tx_utxos

There are also other options like [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.dev/) or [DB sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync).